# Accessing network shares on computer connected to ICS in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-shares, home-networking, windows-networking

Computer A is running Windows 10 Pro and is connected to the internet via wifi and has the IP 10.10.10.10.  It's sharing that connection via ICS to its ethernet connection, which is connected to the internet-in port on a router and uses the static IP 192.168.137.1.  Computer B is connected via ethernet to that router and is running Linux and set up as a samba file server with IP 192.168.1.111.

Computer B can connect to the internet and ping Computer A via the IP 192.168.137.1, but Computer A cannot find Computer B.

I want to be able to connect from Computer A to Computer B.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, trying to share internet from Computer A and communicate back to Computer B for file-sharing. The difference between our setups however is that in my setup: Computer A connected first to a 4-port switch *and then* to the router. Just that extra step is all. But to answer your question: what I ended up doing to get the two to communicated was using port forwarding (1-65535) from the router to Computer B's LAN IP (192.168.2.xx). From Computer A I was able to connect to Copmuter B via the router's IP (192.168.137.xx). I may be mistaken but I think file transfer ports for windows are 137-139, 445.

My use case had no obligations to Computers C, D and E.